# Image displaying only binary value

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimageview, nsdate

I stored images into database table through URL. After im using to fetch that image from URL. I inserted successfully. The images having URL path. But when im fetching it's displaying binary values `<Mydata: 0x71756b0>`. What is this?

code:

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSData* data = nil;

       // UIImage *image = nil;

       // const char *sql = "SELECT product_image FROM product order by order_by";

         const char *sql = "SELECT product_image FROM product";

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
      //  int catID = 0;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
Mydata *Mylist = [[Mydata alloc]init];

                int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2);
                data       = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length:length];
              //  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                 Mylist.photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                NSLog(@"my list is %@",Mylist);

                [mArray addObject:Mylist];

}
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    else {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
    }
}
```

Image display:

```
int Width = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {


      NSLog(@"index %@", mArray[i]);



     imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

        Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

        [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

        [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [imgView1 setImage:((Mydata *)[mArray objectAtIndex:i]).photo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];

        //  [myScroll addSubview:imgView1];



    }
```

Comment: There's nothing called `Mydata` in the code you have pasted.

Comment: sorry. check edited question from this line Mydata *Mylist = [[Mydata alloc]init];

Comment: You are logging address of the instance, which is showing correctly. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the images are not displaying when click the button. check edited question

Comment: Check the data, is it downloaded correctly? Is it getting stored in DB correctly? Also, try setting the image read from DB to a simple `UIImageView`.

Comment: @Amar: Image URL are storing to DB correctly. But images are not displaying when i use UIImageView also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in place of storing image in database, store only URL link in DB.

use ASyncImageView for fetching image from URL.

so image is fetched only one time from server and store locally.

Comment: I stored URL link only not in image.